# Static Linking of Emacs for Windows using win-builds

Tags: emacs, mingw-w64

Background: I'm trying to compile Emacs 25 for my Windows desktop. At the moment I'm using win-builds for this (mingw-w64-based).

I passed in the -static flag in LDFLAGS (to configure), and I crash on the error

```
c:/win_builds/msys/1.0/opt/windows_64/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/
../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldbus-1.
```

I'm interpreting this as the absence of a static lib (archive) to link with. I can link using the dlls, but then I have to dump a ton of dlls into my emacs directory. Is there any mechanism for statically linking the executable in this environment?

Answer (score 2):

Win-builds won't enable you achieve to static linking since it only ships shared libraries except for a very few specific cases.

That said I also need to say I see little use in static linking typically since most applications nowadays come with extra files for resources and will therefore need several files, making the ease of deployment of single-file binaries a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what went wrong with win-builds, but I was able to build and statically link successfully using Msys2 and just 1) installing gcc, make, etc., and 2) configuring with the LDFLAGS I mentioned above. So there definitely is a way to do it, and using the Msys2 infrastructure, I was successful.